# react js Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, arrows

Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function .I am getting this error

```
    {product
          .filter((item) => {
            if (search.toString().toLowerCase()) {
              return item;
            } else if (
              item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toString().toLowerCase())
            ) {
              return item;
            }
          })
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here and add your source array and 
You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: there is an `if`, an `else if`, but what if both don't apply?

Comment: You need to add an `else` case

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.filter expects a value to be returned from within the callback function implying whether to keep or reject the current item value

However in your callback function you have if-else-if block where you return the value but if none of the if or else-if conditions match, you don’t return anything which what the error points

You can return false if none of your if or else-if condition matches
Try below:

```
 {product
              .filter((item) => {
                if (search.toString().toLowerCase()) {
                  return item;
                } else if ( 
 item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toString().toLowerCase())
                ) {
                  return item;
                }
               return false;
              })
```